# How do I scrape table data which has dropdown buttton for each row using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Please find the code attached as an image.

[image]

Expected to scrape each row which has a dropdown button and has data in each row once the dropdown button is clicked

[Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fiqcw.png)

**Please help; I have been struggling with this for over a week. Your help in this regard is deeply appreciated.**

Comment: Try to use pandas https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58347261/extracting-table-data-using-selenium-and-python-into-pandas-dataframe

Comment: Please add your code to the question. The Help center explains how to format code blocks. https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: there is no need to click the dropdown button, the details of each row data are already loaded on the page.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you may try:

```py
import time
import selenium.common.exceptions
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
import selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)

driver.get('https://www.knx.org/knx-en/for-professionals/community/partners/?country=120')
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button.btn.btn-primary.cb-enable'))).click()

try:
    # keep clicking the 'load_more' button as many times as it is clickable.
    while True:
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a#knx-load-button.load_more'))).click()
        time.sleep(1)
except selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException:
    pass

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
driver.quit()
table = soup.select_one('table#partner-list')
rows = table.select('tr')
print(f"total rows: {len(rows)}")

for row in rows[1:]:
    print(list(filter(None, row.text.split('\n'))))
    # you can further parse this data as you want
```

output:

```
total rows: 402
['Drasis Automation      ', 'Chennai', ' ', 'Sameera Akbar', 'Bhageeratha Residency , Marshalls Road, Egmore GA Ground Floor', '600008 Chennai              ', 'Phone:  +91.9840396367', 'Website: ', '                      drasisautomation.com                      ', 'Email', 'Link to map', ' Knowledge Tools Engagement\xa0Projects Feedback', ' Total']
['Entelechy Systems      ', 'Mumbai', ' ', 'Bhavesh Doshi', '#2, Damji Shamji Industrial Estate, L.B.S Marg, Vikhroli (w) 00000', '400083 Mumbai              ', 'Phone:  +91.2220289675', 'Mobile:  +91.9820629675', 'Website: ', '                      entelechysystems.com                      ', 'Email', 'Link to map', ' Knowledge Tools Engagement Projects Feedback', ' Total']
['Ocher LV Solutions Pvt Ltd      ', 'Chennai', ' ', 'karthik kumarababu', 'No 3, Apex Plaza, Nungambakkam High Road, Nungambakkam Opp Ispahani Centre', '600034 Chennai              ', 'Phone:  +91.4447460813', 'Mobile:  +91.7200663333', 'Website: ', '                      ocher.co.in                      ', 'Email', 'Link to map', ' Knowledge Tools Engagement\xa0Projects Feedback', ' Total']
['DELPHY AUTOMATION      ', 'Hyderabad', ' ', 'Mohammed junaid Kammur', 'Shanti Nagar, A C Guards, 10-2-287/A/B & C', '500028 Hyderabad              ', 'Phone:  +91.9882456456', 'Website: ', '                      delphyautomation.com                      ', 'Email', 'Link to map', ' Knowledge Tools Engagement Projects Feedback', ' Total']
['Entelechy Systems      ', 'Mumbai', ' ', 'Akshaya Mestry', 'L.B.S. Road, Vikhroli (west) #2, Damji Shamji Industrial Esta', '400083 Mumbai              ', 'Phone:  +91.8108215426', 'Website: ', 'Email', 'Link to map', ' Knowledge Tools Engagement Projects Feedback', ' Total']
['Bitscraft Integration      ', 'Bangalore', ' ', 'Salu Thomas', 'Hesaraghatta #3, HVM Party Complex', '562123 Bangalore              ', 'Phone:  +91.9986233659', 'Mobile:  +91.9986233659', 'Website: ', '                      bitscraftintegration.com                      ', 'Email', 'Link to map', ' Knowledge Tools Engagement Projects Feedback', ' Total']
['VIBHAVA AUTOMATIONS      ', 'Bangalore', ' ', 'Suresh Babu', '19th Cross, 6th Main, Malleswaram, # 3/2, 1st Floor,', '560055 Bangalore              ', 'Phone:  +91.8023464013', 'Mobile:  +91.9845620181', 'Website: ', 'Email', 'Link to map', ' Knowledge Tools Engagement Projects Feedback', ' Total']
['ABB India Ltd      ', 'Bangalore', ' ', 'Sreejith N', 'peenya 2nd phase plot 5&6', '560058 Bangalore              ', 'Phone:  +9108022948543', 'Mobile:  +919945881176', 'Website: ', 'Email', 'Link to map', ' Knowledge Tools Engagement Projects Feedback', ' Total']
:
:
:
['TECHRENAIT SOLUTIONS PVT LTD, PUNE INDIA  411021PUNE      gurjar pramod PASHAN SUS ROAD B21  SAI VIHAR RESIDENCY PUNE Phone:  +91 9689322325 Mobile:  +919689322325   Website:   Email: pramod@techrenait.com Link to map   Knowledge Tools Engagement Projects Feedback Total     ']
['Alba smart automation pvt ltdgurgaon      Kumar Gulshan udyog vihar plotno275 gurgaon Phone:  01244103303 Mobile:  9711169954   Website:   Email: support@albasmart.com Link to map   Knowledge Tools Engagement Projects Feedback Total     ']
['Schneider Electric India Pvt. Ltd.Gurgaon      Singh Divleen DLF Cyber City, Phase 2 Building No.10 C, 9th Floor Gurgaon Phone:  +91.12439404000 Mobile:  +91.9910031711   Website:   Email: divleen.singh@in.schneider-electric.com Link to map   Knowledge Tools Engagement Projects Feedback Total     ']
['VINOD VALECHAMUMBAI      VALECHA VINOD AGARWAL INDUSTRIAL ESTATE NO 2, UNIT NO 7, SATIVALI ROAD, VASAI EAST 7 MUMBAI Phone:   Mobile:     Website:   Email: francolightings21@gmail.com Link to map   Knowledge Tools Engagement Projects Feedback Total     ']
['Entelechy SystemsMumbai      Choudhar Sandeep L.B.S. Road 122789 Mumbai Phone:  +91.2242258200 Mobile:  +91.9821822715   Website:   Email: c.sandeep@entelechysystems.com Link to map   Knowledge Tools Engagement Projects Feedback Total     ']
['Kamlakar NandoskarMumbai      Nandoskar Kamlakar Santacruz  Pathuck college  Mumbai Phone:  +91.8108767404 Mobile:  +91.8108767404   Website:   Email: kamlakarnandoskar@gmail.com Link to map   Knowledge Tools Engagement Projects Feedback Total     ']
['Sandesh GholeNalasopara (E), Vasai, Palghar      Ghole Sandesh M. D. Nagar, Achole Road G-105, Chandresh Shraddha CHSL Nalasopara (E), Vasai, Palghar Phone:   Mobile:     Website:   Email: sandeshghole@gmail.com Link to map   Knowledge Tools Engagement Projects Feedback Total     ']
```